How to fix cpp random crashes
This C++ program i have written keeps crashing when I run it.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void compile_program() {
    cout << "worked";
    string *cppfile;
    string *outputfile;

    cout << "FILENAME: ";
    cin >> *cppfile;
    cout << endl << "OUTPUT FILE: ";
    cin >> *outputfile;
    cout << endl;

    string command = "g++ " + *cppfile + " -o " + *outputfile;

    system(command.c_str());
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        cout << "Welcome to the program loader." << endl;
        cout << "OPTION 1: Compile program" << endl;
        cout << "OPTION 2: Run program" << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        char *opt;
        cin >> opt;
        cout << endl;
        if (opt == "1" || opt == "a" || opt == "A") {
            compile_program();
        } else if (opt == "2" || opt == "b" || opt == "B") {
            // run_program();
        }
    }
}

After I give it an option, it just waits...
... then crashes.
Any help?

string *cppfile; is a pointer to a std::string, which you never allocate.  Start by changing all pointer declaration like string *cppfile; to string cppfile; and report back, eg string outputfile; and char opt; and any others.

Please review The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List and find a good book.

(opt == "1" || opt == "a" || opt == "A") will never be true. You are comparing pointers. Pointers are not what they point to.

Please go back to the start of your beginners material (books, tutorials, class-notes, etc.) and refresh the basics.

Step 1, don't use pointers.  (You can use them later.  But for learning, no need to use pointers.)

char *opt; cin >> opt; Boom. Don't use pointers until you understand them and have a use for them. opt is not initialized. Attempting to use it like this is death to your program. Also, as of C++20, this precise overload of operator>> has been changed and this form is no longer valid. Possibly you want char opt; std::cin >> opt;

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

you just have to remove any * from your code. How did they end up there in the first place? And char literals use single quotes '1'. Double quotes is for string literals.

fwiw, there is nothing random here. Using "random" for "i dont understand" can lead to confusion and misunderstandings because its actual meaning is distinct from that. You will find it easier to find and fix your problems if you acknowledge what actually happens, your program crashes very reliably.

"After I give it an option" -- If that part works, omit it from your example code. It looks like you did strip out the code for "option 2", which is good, but not enough. Keep removing things that work until you are left with a minimal example. In this case, try removing the menu, which could leave your main function looking like int main() { compile_program(); }.

FYI, you can reduce the quantity of comparisons by converting tolower() or toupper() before comparing.  See alsostd::transform for converting std::string to all lower case or all upper case.

Please recommend to your instructor for them to offer a lecture or two on debugging.  The sooner, the better.

The statement using namespace std; opens up a can of worms.  Try only picking the functionality that you are using instead of the whole std namespace.  Try using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::string; for example.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai  — Brilliant: Using "random" for "I don't understand"...!

can people just chill im a kid bruh. please

@HectorRobertson This site can be quite hostile to newbies sadly. This isn't a good question as it's very basic and you should indeed be sitting down over this code with someone who can point out conflict between what you intended and what's actually happening (and later learn how to fix most crashes with sanitizers), but there are better ways to phrase it.


You are trying to dereference the uninitialized pointers, such as:


cin >> *cppfile;


cin >> *outputfile;

To fix this, change the type of these variables to "std::string" objects and use "std::cin" to directly assign values to them.

Change opt from "char*" to a "char" type.
Replace the double quotes in the comparison with "opt" to single quotes:


if (opt == "1" || opt == "a" || opt == "A")

to

if (opt == '1' || opt == 'a' || opt == 'A')


Include the string library to ensure the program works properly:


#include "string"

